# How much sugar to real apple ratio?

Tags: yeast, cider, first-time-brewer, sugar

So I was going to try an apple cider up to around 12%. So how much sugar will I get roughly per apple and how much additional sugar should I add. The apples are a small granny smith kind. Currently I have chopped them up and they have been sitting for a few days to brown them. I will then boil them with some brown sugar and a couple of other things before transferring them to a carboy.

Answer (score 2):

When adding sugar to boost a ciders ABV it becomes an Apple Wine.

Apple juice tends to have a SG of 1.035 to 1.040, to hit 12% you need about 1.095 OG and a FG of 1.005 (semi dry)

In 5 gallons this would be about 6lb of sugar.

- Sorry for the vague terms like "about", but there's a lot of unknowns until you actually press the apples to get a SG and have a final gravity target. 
  Cider/Apple wines FG's range from 0.995-1.020 depending on how dry to sweet you want it. Having this will also change the yeast and fermentation process a lot.